# Unable to download file from blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, blobstore

I have successfully uploaded a file to blobstore using [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) code.

But I am **unable to download it**.
What I am doing is:

```
`class PartnerFileDownloadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, blob_key):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
    logging.info('I am here.')  //This gets printed successfully.
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
    logging.info(blob_info)   //This gets logged too. 
    self.send_blob(blob_info)`
```

I have also tried:

```
blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key).read()
```

and I get file data in string form but I can not write it to file, as local file system can not be accessed from within a handler, I guess.

The way I am uploading a file is the only way in my project so I can not use the usual way specified in the Google's official tutorial. Also **The file I am uploading to blobstore is not present at my local file syatem, I pick it from a URL**, perhaps this is the problem why I am not able to download the file.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use **resource** instead of **blob_key** from your code sample?

```
class PartnerFileDownloadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
def get(self, blob_key):
resource = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
self.send_blob(resource)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use DownloadHandler as this:
      from mimetypes import guess_type

```
    def mime_type(filename):
        return guess_type(filename)[0]
    class Thumbnailer(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
        def get(self , blob_key):

            if blob_key:
                blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)


                if blob_info:
                    save_as1 =  blob_info.filename
                    mime_type=mime_type(blob_info.filename)
                    self.send_blob(blob_info,content_type=mime_type,save_as=save_as1)
```